# addMouseListener to labels within an arraylist

Tags: java, mouseevent

This is my first post here, I've tried searching for an existing topic but couldn't find anything specifically relating to an array list.

I need to set addMouseListeners to all of my `jlabels` that are generated in an `ArrayList`.

There are two arrays, `smLabelList` and `lrLabelList`. These contain two types of JLabels, `smBay` and `lrBay` - these are generated and added to my panels using a for-loop.

The first question being, what is the best way to add action listeners to objects within the list?

The second is, would the getSource() == smBay or the smLabelList array?

Many thanks in advance - I'm new to java this year, have only been studying a few months.

```
package Despatch;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.event.*;
import javax.swing.*;
import java.util.*;

class GUI extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

    JPanel buttonPnl;
    JPanel topPnl;
    JPanel bottomPnl;
    JLabel smBay;
    JButton boxButton; //creates variable
    JButton tubeButton;
    JButton envelopeButton;
    JButton clearButton;
    JButton saveButton;
    JButton loadButton;
    JButton chargeButton;
    JButton totalChargeButton;

    int smCount = 0;
    int lrCount = 0;
    double currentCharge;

    private ArrayList<Parcel> smParcel = new ArrayList<Parcel>(9);
    private ArrayList<Parcel> lrParcel = new ArrayList<Parcel>(4);

    //array list for bay JLabels
    List<JLabel> smLabelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();
    List<JLabel> lrLabelList = new ArrayList<JLabel>();

    //constructor to draw GUI
    GUI() {

        // draw top panel for small/medium parcels
        topPnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(3, 3));
        topPnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        topPnl.setOpaque(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < (3 * 3); i++) {

            JLabel smBay = new JLabel();
            smBay.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));

            smLabelList.add(smBay);
            topPnl.add(smBay);
        }

        // draw bottom panel for large parcels
        bottomPnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 4));
        bottomPnl.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
        bottomPnl.setOpaque(true);

        for (int i = 0; i < (1 * 4); i++) {

            JLabel lrBay = new JLabel();
            lrBay.setBorder(BorderFactory.createLineBorder(Color.BLUE));
            lrLabelList.add(lrBay);
            bottomPnl.add(lrBay);
        }

        //add actionlisteners to bays???
            for (int i = 0; i < 9; ++i) {
            smLabelList.get(i).addMouseListener(null);
        }



        buttonPnl = new JPanel(new GridLayout(8, 1));// create new button panel object

        boxButton = new JButton("Add Box Package");
        buttonPnl.add(boxButton);

        tubeButton = new JButton("Add Tube Package");
        buttonPnl.add(tubeButton); // draws tube button

        envelopeButton = new JButton("Add Envelope Package");
        buttonPnl.add(envelopeButton); // draws envelope button

        clearButton = new JButton("Clear");
        buttonPnl.add(clearButton); // draws envelope button

        saveButton = new JButton("Save");
        buttonPnl.add(saveButton); // draws save button

        loadButton = new JButton("Load");
        buttonPnl.add(loadButton);// draws load button;

        chargeButton = new JButton("Current Charge");
        buttonPnl.add(chargeButton);// draws charge button;

        totalChargeButton = new JButton("Total Charge");
        buttonPnl.add(totalChargeButton);// draws charge button;

        boxButton.addActionListener(this);
        tubeButton.addActionListener(this);
        envelopeButton.addActionListener(this);
        clearButton.addActionListener(this);
        saveButton.addActionListener(this);
        loadButton.addActionListener(this);
        chargeButton.addActionListener(this);
        totalChargeButton.addActionListener(this);



    }//end of construct

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent ae) {
        //find out which button has been pressed
        if (ae.getSource() == boxButton) {

            addBox();//calls the addBox method.

        } else if (ae.getSource() == tubeButton) {

            addTube();
        } else if (ae.getSource() == envelopeButton) {
            addEnvelope();
        } else if (ae.getSource() == clearButton) {
            clear();
        } else if (ae.getSource() == saveButton) {
            System.out.println("you pressed the save button");
        } else if (ae.getSource() == loadButton) {
            System.out.println("you pressed the load button");
        } else if (ae.getSource() == chargeButton) {
            currentCharge();

        } else {
            System.out.println("you pressed the total button");

        }

    }

    public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mouseExited(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mousePressed(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent me) {
    }

    public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent me) {

        if (me.getSource() == smBay) {
            if (SwingUtilities.isLeftMouseButton(me)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you pressed the left mouse button");
            } else if (SwingUtilities.isMiddleMouseButton(me)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you pressed the middle mouse button");
            } else if (SwingUtilities.isRightMouseButton(me)) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "you pressed the right mouse button");

            }
        } else {
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "doesn't matter");
        }
    }

    public void addBox() {

        int id = 0;
        while (id == 0) {
            try {
                String idStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter Box ID");
                id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid ID");
            }
        }

        int dz = 0;
        while ((dz < 1) || (dz > 3)) {
            try {
                String dzStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a delivery zone");
                dz = Integer.parseInt(dzStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid delivery zone between 1 and 3");
            }
        }
        char dzChar = '0';
        if (dz == 1) {
            dzChar = '1';
        } else if (dz == 2) {
            dzChar = '2';
        } else {
            dzChar = '3';
        }

        //function to convert dz integar to a char.
        int boxL = 0;
        while (boxL == 0) {
            try {
                String boxLStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter box length");
                boxL = Integer.parseInt(boxLStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid length");
            }
        }

        int boxW = 0;
        while (boxW == 0) {
            try {
                String boxWStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter box width");
                boxW = Integer.parseInt(boxWStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid width");
            }
        }

        int boxH = 0;
        while (boxH == 0) {
            try {
                String boxHStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter box height in cm");
                boxH = Integer.parseInt(boxHStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid height");
            }
        }

        if (boxH >= 150) //checks if box height is over 150cm
        {
            if (lrCount < 4) {// secondary validation to check that that large array has spare slot

                lrParcel.add(new Box(id, dzChar, boxL, boxW, boxH) {
                });

                JLabel lrBay = lrLabelList.get(lrCount); //create new label from labels array refercing lrCounter
                lrBay.setIcon((lrParcel.get(lrCount).getImage()));

                currentCharge = (currentCharge + lrParcel.get(lrCount).getCharge());
                lrCount++;

                for (Parcel value : lrParcel) {
                    System.out.println(value);

                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, there is no room for this parcel!");

            }
        } else {
            if (smCount < 9) {

                smParcel.add(new Box(id, dzChar, boxL, boxW, boxH) {
                });

                JLabel smBay = smLabelList.get(smCount); //create new label from labels array refercing lrCounter
                smBay.setIcon((smParcel.get(smCount).getImage()));

                currentCharge = (currentCharge + smParcel.get(smCount).getCharge());
                smCount++;
                //loop to print contents of array - for testing only.
                for (Parcel value : smParcel) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, there is no room for this parcel!");
            }

        }

    }

    public void addTube() {

        int id = 0;
        while (id == 0) {
            try {
                String idStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter Tube ID");
                id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid ID");
            }
        }

        int dz = 0;
        while ((dz < 1) || (dz > 3)) {
            try {
                String dzStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a delivery zone");
                dz = Integer.parseInt(dzStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid delivery zone between 1 and 3");
            }
        }
        char dzChar = '0';
        if (dz == 1) {
            dzChar = '1';
        } else if (dz == 2) {
            dzChar = '2';
        } else {
            dzChar = '3';
        }

        int tubeL = 0;
        while ((tubeL >= 250 || tubeL <= 0)) {
            try {
                String tubeLStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter tube length(cm)");
                tubeL = Integer.parseInt(tubeLStr);
            } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid length(cm)");
            }
        }

        if (tubeL >= 150) //checks if tube height is over 1500cm
        {
            if (lrCount < 4) {// secondary validation to check that that large array has spare slot

                lrParcel.add(new Tube(id, dzChar, tubeL) {
                });

                JLabel lrBay = lrLabelList.get(lrCount); //create new label from labels array refercing lrCounter
                lrBay.setIcon((lrParcel.get(lrCount).getImage()));

                currentCharge = (currentCharge + lrParcel.get(lrCount).getCharge());
                lrCount++;

                for (Parcel value : lrParcel) {
                    System.out.println(value);

                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, there is no room for this parcel!");

            }
        } else {
            if (smCount < 9) {

                smParcel.add(new Tube(id, dzChar, tubeL) {
                });

                JLabel smBay = smLabelList.get(smCount); //create new label from labels array refercing lrCounter
                smBay.setIcon((smParcel.get(smCount).getImage()));

                currentCharge = (currentCharge + smParcel.get(smCount).getCharge());
                smCount++;

                //loop to print contents of array - for testing only.
                for (Parcel value : smParcel) {
                    System.out.println(value);
                }
            } else {
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, there is no room for this parcel!");
            }

        }

    }

    public void addEnvelope() {

        {

            int id = 0;
            while (id == 0) {
                try {
                    String idStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter Envelope ID");
                    id = Integer.parseInt(idStr);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid ID");
                }
            }

            int dz = 0;
            while ((dz < 1) || (dz > 3)) {
                try {
                    String dzStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter a delivery zone");
                    dz = Integer.parseInt(dzStr);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid delivery zone between 1 and 3");
                }
            }
            char dzChar = '0';
            if (dz == 1) {
                dzChar = '1';
            } else if (dz == 2) {
                dzChar = '2';
            } else {
                dzChar = '3';
            }

            char envelopeS = '0';
            while (envelopeS != 's' && envelopeS != 'm' && envelopeS != 'l') {
                try {
                    String envelopeSStr = JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Please enter the envelope size(s,m,l)");
                    envelopeS = envelopeSStr.charAt(0);
                } catch (NumberFormatException nfe) {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Invalid input, please enter a valid size(s,m,l)");
                }
            }

            if (envelopeS == 'l') //checks if envelope height is over 1500cm
            {
                if (lrCount < 4) {// secondary validation to check that that large array has spare slot

                    lrParcel.add(new Envelope(id, dzChar, envelopeS) {
                    });

                    JLabel lrBay = lrLabelList.get(lrCount); //create new label from labels array refercing lrCounter
                    lrBay.setIcon((lrParcel.get(lrCount).getImage()));

                    currentCharge = (currentCharge + lrParcel.get(lrCount).getCharge());
                    lrCount++;

                    for (Parcel value : lrParcel) {
                        System.out.println(value);

                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, there is no room for this parcel!");

                }
            } else {
                if (smCount < 9) {

                    smParcel.add(new Envelope(id, dzChar, envelopeS) {
                    });

                    JLabel smBay = smLabelList.get(smCount); //create new label from labels array refercing lrCounter
                    smBay.setIcon((smParcel.get(smCount).getImage()));

                    currentCharge = (currentCharge + smParcel.get(smCount).getCharge());
                    smCount++;
                    //loop to print contents of array - for testing only.
                    for (Parcel value : smParcel) {
                        System.out.println(value);
                    }
                } else {
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Sorry, there is no room for this parcel!");
                }

            }

        }

    }

    public void currentCharge() {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Total charge for current items is " + currentCharge);

    }

    public void clear() {


        //clears each bay, removes icon
        for (int i = 0; i < smCount; ++i) {
            smLabelList.get(i).setIcon(null);
        }

        //clears each bay, removes icon
        for (int i = 0; i < lrCount; ++i) {
            lrLabelList.get(i).setIcon(null);
        }

        smCount = 0;
        lrCount = 0;
        smParcel.clear();//cleaers the sm parcel array
        lrParcel.clear();// clears the lr parcel array

        currentCharge = 0;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way I can think of to add action listeners is to just do it manually if you have different action listeners for each label, or do it in a loop if you have the same listener for each label.

```
for (JLabel label : smLabelList)
{
    label.addActionListener(myActionListener);
}
for (JLabel label : lrLabelList)
{
    label.addActionListener(myActionListener);
}
```

As for your second question, getSource () returns the object that generated the action, which would be the label itself, not the array. The label doesn't know that it is in an array, so it would have no way of returning that array in the first place.